# Lightweight cross-platform C++ library for RSA digital signature verification

Tags: c++, cryptography, windows-runtime

Could you advise any lightweight cross-platform C++ library for verifying RSA digital signatures? I would like to use the same codebase on **WinRT**, **Android** and **iOS**.

I have looked at **CryptoC++**, **Botan** and **OpenSSL**, but they seem to be rather heavyweight, and quite difficult to build.

**LibTomCrypt** seems to be a bit simpler than the rest, however I couldn't get it to compile in a Visual Studio project yet.

Has anyone managed to get LibTomCrypt to work on WinRT? Is there any other lightweight library to use?

Comment: If anyone interested, I managed to get LibTomCrypt build and work on WinRT, details here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/f57217ca-7431-4f6b-8521-6d08790ccc98